# Rails 4, Devise & Polymorphic Associations

Tags: ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

Here's my functioning code to register a type of user called mentor via a Rails 4 JSON API.

Now I'm wondering, is there a better way to go about this? A more cleaner/simpler approach where Rails can automagically create the user/mentor association.

Currently I'm setting it manually in the `create` method which doesn't seem right. So I just want to make sure there is no better way out there of going about this.

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :role, :polymorphic => true
end
```

**models/mentor.rb**

```
class Mentor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :role
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

**controllers/api/V1/mentors_controller.rb**

```
class Api::V1::MentorsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @mentor = Mentor.new(mentor_params)
    @user.role = @mentor
    @user.save!
    @mentor.user_id = @user.id
    @mentor.save!
    respond_with :api, @mentor
  end

  private

  def mentor_params
    params.require(:mentor).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
  end
end
```

**UPDATE - 10/01/2013**

I make some more inroads with this. Here's what I have now:

**controllers/api/V1/mentors_controller.rb**

```
class Api::V1::MentorsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    @mentor = Mentor.new(mentor_params)
    @mentor.user.save!
    @mentor.user_id = @mentor.user.id
    @mentor.save!
    respond_with :api, @mentor
  end

  private

  def mentor_params
    params.require(:mentor).permit(:first_name, :last_name, user_attributes: [:email, :password])
  end
end
```

But I still have to set the user_id manually. Only doing `Mentor.create(mentor_params)` fails to set the user_id. Any way to get around that?

Comment: Have you tried to make a `mentor=` method in the user? Rails should take the params[:user][:mentor] and pass that to the `mentor=` method. Then you could build your Mentor.new and do all the other stuff in your user class. Your controller should become just `@user = User.new(user_params)` `@user.save!` `respond_with :api, @user.mentor`.

Comment: @jeremywoertink I don't want to put everything in one User controller. I will have couple of different user types with different fields. So I'd rather separate the logic into their own controllers.

Answer (score 1):

This is off the top of my head but the basic idea goes something like this.

Create a form with a nested resource

```
form_for @mentor do |f|
  f.input :mentor_val
  f.fields_for :user do |m|
    m.input :user_val
```

It should post a params object with a format something like this:

```
mentor: {
  mentor_val: 'blah'
  user_attributes: {
    user_val: 'foo'
  }
}
```

Now since you have included `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your Mentor model, Rails automatically added a `user_attributes=` method to `Mentor` which will build the user model, including setting the relationship. This means that to create both models, all you need to do in the controller is call

```
@mentor.create(params)
```

Comment: I actually tried this approach but it completely ignored the user params and didn't create any association between the two. Similar experience as [this person](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666007/devise-polymorphic-association-nested-attributes-with-simple-form-using-rails-4/18704223#18704223).

Comment: I realized I was naming the attributes wrong in my request. So your suggestion worked but only partially (see above).

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question on your update, try adding the id to your params whitelist:

```
def mentor_params
    params.require(:mentor).permit(:first_name, :last_name,user_attributes: [:id, :email, :password])
end
```